# convert dae to gltf, horizontal vector invalidation

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, gltf, collada

I converted `.dae` to `.gltf` through this [tool](https://products.aspose.com/3d/java/conversion/dae-to-gltf/), and display through `three.js`, and found that the horizontal vector of the model seems to be invalid.

[Example file](https://gitlab.com/po_developer/dae-file-example/-/tree/main/1b03f03d-88a2-4c12-9c75-82539a48c081)

Convert tool interface:
[image]

The situation when I use `.dae` file to display:

```
   let loaderDae = new ColladaLoader();

   loaderDae.load(`assets/untitled.dae`, (dae: any) => {
      this.buildingModel = dae.scene;
      this.buildingModel.position.multiplyScalar(0);
      this.scene.add(this.buildingModel);
    });
```

[image]

The situation when I use `.gltf` file to display:

```
  let loaderGLTF = new GLTFLoader();
  loaderGLTF.load(`assets/untitled.glft`, (glft: any) => {
          this.buildingModel = glft.scene;
          this.buildingModel.position.multiplyScalar(0);
          this.scene.add(this.buildingModel);
        });
```

[image]

After zooming in(or out):
[image]

The gloss of the texture is also not the same. I don't know if it's a file conversion problem or a lighting problem. I am `using ambientLight`:

```
 let ambColor = new THREE.Color('rgb(118, 240, 147');
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(ambColor);
    this.ambientLight.name = 'testname';
    this.scene.add(this.ambientLight)
```

Comment: If you haven't changed the ambient light settings for displaying both its unlikely that the gloss would change as a result of different lighting. Have you tried to recreate the error using another [converter](https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/dae-to-gltf)?

Comment: @meropis I tried the `aspose` tool and the situation was the same as the problem I described. The horizontal lines fail, and the texture gloss are different.

Comment: Interesting, it is quite likely that `.dae` and `.gltf` files may have different plane orientations (i.e. x plane in `.dae` is y plane in `.gltf`). The orientation issue is easily fixed with a y rotation (`<model>.rotation.y += Math.PI / 2`).

Comment: `<model>` << What is this? Taking my code as an example, I try to modify it like this:`this.buildingModel = gltf.scene.rotation.y += Math.PI / 2`, but I get the error message and it doesn't work.

Comment: `this.buildingModel.rotation.y += Math.PI / 2` (since `this.buildingModel` is your reference to the 3D model.)

Comment: The horizontal vector is successfully changed, but the angle of the transformation is still not right.

Comment: I'm unsure which axis it will be on because I don't know which is which from your code, but it will be a 90 degree turn in one of the three directions. That is 6 possibilities. Try them.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try again. I don't know if it is a good way to rotate the angle manually, when I have many files to deal with. Gloss is also still an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247520/discussion-between-meropis-and-finn).